# Firebug - Object /undefined/

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, console.log

i have a "simple" quest.
In one of my web Apps when i write in the firbug console one of my object, firebug return me the object with the text "/undefined/" after.
like:

> Object /undefined/

what firebug what he means when firebug says when return this syntax of log in console?

I can't write all code here, but i can tell that my object is instanced from a funciton object like:

```
var Entita = function(options){
  for(var prop in options) {
    this[prop] = options[prop];
  }
  .. base method end prop ...
}

myNewObject = new Entita({
 ..prop end method that extend Entita...
})
```

...

> console.log(myNewObject)
>
> return: 
>   "object/undefined/"

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Firefox 25.0 + Firebug 1.12.4 on Win8.1. Which versions do you have? Can you provide a complete test case?

Comment: Hi, Sebastian i think that problem is FF & OS version... because now with FF Aurora 27 & MAC OSX 10.9... when i log the object the console return me only the object without any other string like "/undefined/". Thx however...

Comment: I see. Did you create a new Firefox profile for that? Since I can't reproduce your issue, it may also have another reason. If that issue reappears, please [file a bug in the Firebug issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry), so it can be fixed.

Comment: My old mac was an OSX 10.5.8 with FF 18 (I think), I do not think that it is useful to make a report for a wild version that old. However when i use my old mac I report this bug.

Comment: Ok, that old Firefox versions are not supported by Firebug anymore. So please just report the bug, if it reappears on the current stable Firefox/Firebug versions.